# How to switch browsers in Robot Framework using Browser library?

Tags: browser, robotframework

could someone post example code for creating two browser instances and switching between those using Robot Framework's Browser (NOT using SeleniumLibrary) library?

Namely: how to obtain correct `browser id` for [Switch Browser](https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Switch%20Browser) keyword.

`Switch Browser    ${browser_id}`

Full code so far:

```
Library          Browser
Library          String
Library          Collections

** Variables **
${url1}=    https://www.google.com
${url1}=    https://www.bing.com
@{browser_ids}=    Create List

** Test Cases **
Open Browser 1
    [Tags]   UI    dev
    New Browser    chromium    headless=false
    New Context    viewport={'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}
    New Page       ${url1}

Open Browser 2
    [Tags]   UI    dev
    New Browser    chromium    headless=false
    New Context    viewport={'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}
    New Page       ${url2}

Page Switch tests

    [Tags]   UI    dev

    Switch to Browser1
    Get Element   text=Gmail
    Switch to Browser2
    Get Element    text=© 2021 Microsoft


** Keywords **
Switch to Browser2
    Switch Page    ${browser_ids}[1]

Switch to Browser1
    Switch Page    ${browser_ids}[0]

Store Active Browser Id
    ${active_id}=    Get Page Ids   ACTIVE    ACTIVE    ACTIVE
    Log To Console    ${active_id}
    ${active_id}=    Split String    ${active_id}[0]    =
    Log To Console    ${active_id}[1]
    Append To List    ${BROWSER_IDS}    ${active_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Browser
Suite Setup  Setup


*** Test Cases ***
Do something with page1
   Switch Page  ${PAGE1}

Do something with page2
   Switch Page  ${PAGE1}

Page switchy
   Switch Page  ${PAGE1}
   Get Element   text=Gmail
   Switch Page  ${PAGE2}
   Get Element   text=© 2021 Microsoft

*** Keywords ***
Setup
   ${PAGE1}=  New Page  https://www.google.com
   Set Suite variable  ${PAGE1}
   ${PAGE2}=  New Page  https://www.bing.com
   Set Suite variable  ${PAGE2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser library has automatic teardown for Browser/Context/Page instances, so you have to create all needed instances of those in Suite Setup. Solution below:

```
*** Settings ***
Library          Browser
#Library          OperatingSystem
Library          Collections
Library          String
Suite Setup      Create Suite Ecosystem

*** Variables ***

@{bids}
@{cids}
@{pids}
${url1}=    https://www.google.com
${url2}=    https://www.bing.com

*** Test Cases ***

Setup Verification
    [Tags]   UI    dev
    ${bids}=   Get Browser Ids
    Log To console    ${bids}

    ${bids}=   Get Context Ids
    Log To console    ${cids}

    ${pids}=   Get Page Ids
    Log To console    ${pids}

Page Switch tests
    [Tags]   UI    dev
    Switch to Page 1
    Get Element   text=Gmail
    Switch to Page 2
    Get Element   text=© 2021 Microsoft

** Keywords **

Switch to Page 1
    Switch Page     ${pids}[0]

Switch to Page 2
    Switch Page     ${pids}[1]

Store Active Browser Id
    ${active_id}=    Get Browser Ids   ACTIVE
    #${active_id}=    Split String    ${active_id}[0]    =
    Log To Console    ${active_id}[0]
    Append To List    ${bids}    ${active_id}[0]

Store Active Context Id
    ${active_id}=    Get Context Ids   ACTIVE    ACTIVE
    Log To Console    ${active_id}
    # ${active_id}=    Split String    ${active_id}[0]    =
    Log To Console    ${active_id}[0]
    Append To List    ${cids}    ${active_id}[0]

Store Active Page Id
    [Arguments]    ${new_id}
    ${active_id}=    Get Page Ids   ACTIVE    ACTIVE    ACTIVE
    # ${active_id}=    Split String    ${active_id}[0]    =
    Log To Console    ${active_id}[0]
    Append To List    ${pids}    ${new_id}

Create Suite Ecosystem
    # Create 1B-1C-2P Ecosystem

    # 1st Browser
    New Browser    chromium    headless=false
    Store Active Browser Id

    # 1st Context of 1st Browser
    New Context    viewport={'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}
    Store Active Context Id

    # 1st Page of 1st Context of 1st Context
    New Page       ${url1}
    ${current}=    Switch Page    CURRENT
    Store Active Page Id    ${current}

    # 2nd Page of 1st Context of 1st Context
    New Page       ${url2}
    ${current}=    Switch Page    CURRENT
    Store Active Page Id    ${current}
```